# Jacobi method generates a convergent succession for $\,X\,$ if and only if $\,c \in ]- 1, 1[.$

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Consider the system of equations $AX = B$, where
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}2 & c & 0 \\ c & 1 & c \\ 0 & c & 2\end{bmatrix} $$
and $c ∈ \Bbb R \setminus \{−2, −1, 1, 2\}$. Which of the following
statement is true?

The answer is:
Jacobi's method generates a convergent succession for $X$ if and only if $c ∈] - 1, 1 [$.

My doubts is: I've done it and got
$$ G = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &-1/2c& 0 \\ -c & 0 & -c\\ 0 &-1/2c & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
where $G$ is a  3×3 matrix

and so  $\|G\|_\infty= \max\bigl(|1/2*c|,|2c|,1/|2|c\bigr) = 2|c| < 1 \iff |c| < 1/2$

why is this wrong?

The statements are:

a) Jacobi's method generates a convergent succession for X if and only if c ∈] −1/√2 , 1/√2 [

b) Jacobi's method generates a convergent succession for X if and only if c ∈] −1/2,1/2 [

c) Jacobi's method generates a convergent succession for X if and only if c ∈] - 1, 1 [;

d) Jacobi's method generates a convergent succession for X if and only if c ∈] - 2, 2 [;

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math.

Comment: What are the statements?

Comment: already add it @xpaul

Comment: What is your $G$?

Comment: Is the general method, G = −D ^ (- 1) * (L + U)

in all cases L being the lower triangular matrix in the strict sense, D the diagonal matrix and U the upper triangular matrix in the strict sense.

Comment: The maximum of $\frac{1}{2|c|},2|c|,\frac{1}{2|c|}$ is not always $2|c|$. If you use the norm 1 instead, and knowing that Jacobi method converges iff $\rho(G)<1$ where $\rho$ is the spectral radius and that $\rho(G)<\|G\|_1$ you get the correct answer.

Comment: @MarcMagaña is not 1/2|c| is 1/2 * |c|

Comment: You can always compute the spectral radius of $G$, it's not difficult to do in this case. $$\left|\begin{matrix}
0-\lambda & \frac{c}{2} & 0 \\
c & 0-\lambda & c \\
0 & \frac{c}{2} & 0-\lambda
\end{matrix}\right|=-\lambda(\lambda-c)(\lambda+c),$$ so the largest of its eigenvalues is $c$. Therfore, the method converges if $c\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: but if i do it the other way max{1/2*|c|,2|c|,1/2*|c|} = 2|c| < 1 why is this wrong? i still didn't understand... @MarcMagaña